# How can I customize the org.controlsfx.dialog.ProgressDialog from ControlsFX

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

I created my own custom progress dialog to handle server calls, using a framework that will display pop up the Alert while the background thread is running.  I didn't use Service/Task to accomplish the background threading and therefore, I couldn't use the ControlsFX ProgressAlert.

However for things that take place solely on the UI, I would rather use that if I can.  I can't figure out how to make these look the same.

This is what I would like:

[image]

This is how I attempted to make this work with ControlsFX:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(service);
        pd.getDialogPane().setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/myImage.png").toExternalForm())));
        pd.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/myImage.png").toExternalForm())));
        pd.setContentText("Reprinting Batch Header....");
        pd.setHeaderText("Please Wait...");
        pd.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        pd.initOwner(parent.getPrimaryStage());
        service.start();
```

However this doesn't place my image where I would like it and I am not sure how to change it.

[image]

If possible I would like these to style the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the text match by setting both `title` and `headerText`:

```
pd.setTitle("Please Wait...");
pd.setHeaderText("This will take a moment...");
```

You can set `contextText` as you are now, or your `service`'s `task` can call `updateMessage("some message");`.  This message will be displayed in the progress dialog's `contextText`.  This allows you to update the `contentText` message from the task to let the user know what is going on as the task progresses.

The "info" image is being set via css.  You can change it by replacing the stylesheet being applied to the progress dialog:

```
pd.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().clear();
pd.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add(YourClass.getResource("/path/to/yourcss.css").toExternalForm());
```

Then specify the image in your css:

```
.progress-dialog.dialog-pane {
    -fx-graphic: url("path/to/image.png");
}
```